# Child-Friendly Castles in Switzerland and Germany

Tags: germany, children, switzerland, architecture

Traveling between Geneva, Switzerland and Kempten, Germany. What are some recommendations for castles that would be entertaining for kids 7-10 years old?

Ideally, I would like to find something within 30 minutes off of A1 in Switzerland and A96 and A7 in Germany (basically along a driving route between Geneva and Kempten).

I'm thinking not palaces or ones with long guided-tours, but rather some that kids can wander up towers to explore and learn, see some weapons & armor, and maybe a trebuchet :)

Comment: Search Google for 'Saalburg', the children love it and there's a show. All in German by the way. But overall your question is too broad for the site's q/a format, please narrow the scope a bit.

Comment: This question brings back memories of La Perouse as a kid.

Comment: Saalburg looks great, but it's a long way off the specified route. Andrew, could you clarify La Perouse? Is that in France close to Geneva? I'm not finding a number of castles when searching for that name. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to propose that the hold on this question be removed. I've added a specific route between the two locations already mentioned. I realize there are likely scores of castles along it, which is why I've tried to give a few more details on what we're looking for. Thank you.

Comment: The Munot fortress in Schaffhausen is quite impressive. You might also visit the Rheinfall on the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Chillon Castle](http://www.myswitzerland.com/en-se/chateau-de-chillon-en-montreux.html), located on a rock on the banks of Lake of Geneva near Montreux.

[Kyburg Castle](http://www.myswitzerland.com/en-se/museum-castle-kyburg.html), located between Zurich and Winterthur very close to A1.

Both places are kinds friendly and very close to your route.

Comment: Chillon Castle was great. We also enjoyed the town of Gruyere (closer to A12 than A1, however). In hindsight, this question does have a tremendous number of answers - there are so many castles, city walls and ruins to explore that we probably couldn't have gone wrong.